# Header status showing 404 error. How to fix?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have made login pages outside the wordpress theme folder. The code is running perfectly but there are some errors showing.

1. Header status showing 404 instead 200.
2. Body has class error404.
3. Title is not rendering correctly. I solved it by coding the static javascript line.

**Here is my page outside the WP-Theme:**

```html
<?php include './Logincheck.php'; require( '../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>

<script>
  document.title = "Login - Peerless Institute";
</script>
<?php require( './wp-config.php'); ?>

<div class="main-title">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="main-title__primary">Login</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="master-container">
  <div class="container page type-page" role="main">
    <div id="content">

      <div class="login-content">
        <form action="" method="post">
          <?php echo $ErrorMsg ;?>
          <input type="password" maxlength="100" name="passcode" placeholder="Enter Passcode:" />
          <input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**How to fix this issue ? Please help me out of here.**

Comment: `Header status showing 404 instead 200.` - well, what does that tell you?... the redirection is probably a broken link. `Body has class error404.` - same. `Title is not rendering correctly` - The code you've posted is the correct code, you probably have other errors that prevent this code from running.

Comment: Using the link http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/ tells me its header status.
And In HTML showed wrong rendered body class and title.

Comment: Can't help without more code posted or a live link.

Comment: Here is the link
http://www.peerlessinstitute.com/a/login.php

Comment: I get two errors: 1. It cannot load font awesome, make sure the link is the correct one. 2. `http://www.peerlessinstitute.com/a/login.php Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` - Make sure the link to login.php is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Some of my developer made rule in .htaccess. I changed it according to my terms. It solved.

Thank you for time and consideration.